# using logical operators with characters

Tags: r, character, logical-operators

I have a df with three thousand rows and I would like to create a new column with zeros or ones depending on the word written in a different one.

I have a function which assesses the entry in a column, and if it matches the word I'm looking for, then a "1" is returned in a new column. Like this:

```
 oneorzero <- function(x) {
   if (x["col_one"] == "dog") {
     return("1")
   }
   return("0")
 }
 df["col_two"] = apply(df, 1, oneorzero)
```

I would like to  be able to apply the logical OR operator so that a one will be added when various different words are encountered like this:

```
 oneorzero <- function(x) {
   if (x["col_one"] == "dog" | "cat" | "rat") {
     return("1")
   }
   return("0")
 }
 df["col_two"] = apply(df, 1, oneorzero)
```

But of course that doesn't work because logical operators can only be used on numeric values. Does anyone know how this can be done`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use logical operators on characters, however, you can use them on logical statements. Your `if` statement should look like this:

```
 oneorzero <- function(x) {
   if (x["col_one"] == "dog" | x["col_one"] =="cat" | x["col_one"] =="rat") {
 return("1")
   }
   return("0")
 }
```

In addition, there is a vectorised version of `if` statement called `ifelse`. It can make your code more concise and easy-to-read:

```
df["col_two"]=ifelse(df$col_one=="dog" | df$col_one=="cat" | df$col_one== "rat",1,0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use vectorization and the `%in%` function (see `help("%in%")`, but it should be self-explanatory):

```
as.integer(x["col_one"] %in% c("dog", "cat", "rat"))
```

`as.integer` turns logical values into 0/1.

Answer (score 2):

It's always better to use vectorized solutions in R then cycles. For `data.frame` with 3K rows it's not so important, but for larger ones you'll see great difference in performance.

For your problem I advice to use `grepl` function.

```
# lets generate reproducible example
set.seed(321)
df <- data.frame(col_one = sapply(1:1e3, function(x) 
  paste(sample(c("dog", "cat", "fox", "rat", "bird", "car", "123"), 
               sample(1:7, 1), T), collapse = ",")) )

# how does it look like?
head(df, 10)
#                         col_one
# 1  123,cat,car,bird,rat,dog,fox
# 2               car,rat,cat,123
# 3                          bird
# 4                      bird,fox
# 5                  bird,rat,123
# 6  rat,123,car,bird,cat,dog,fox
# 7                      bird,123
# 8  bird,fox,rat,dog,car,cat,123
# 9                       rat,car
# 10     fox,dog,bird,car,rat,cat

df$col_01 <- +(grepl("dog|cat|rat", df$col_one))
#                          col_one col_01
# 1    123,cat,cat,fox,fox,rat,fox      1
# 2               car,bird,fox,car      0
# 3                           bird      0
# 4                       bird,fox      0
# 5                  bird,bird,123      0
# 6  rat,bird,car,123,rat,dog,bird      1
# 7                      bird,bird      0
# 8  bird,rat,car,dog,bird,rat,car      1
# 9                        rat,123      1
# 10       fox,dog,123,cat,cat,rat      1
```